# Create html table and fill using data in array

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement, html-table

can you help me with looping problem in php? I've been confused for hours because I don't understand deeply

so overall the data below is the result of the clustering calculation - KMeans. The array below is the data that has been grouped.

and the problem is when displaying it, because it's too confusing for me.

so I have an array data like the following.

```
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    array (size=8)
      'Label 1' => int 1
      'Label 2' => int 0
      'Label 3' => int 0
      'Label 4' => int 0
      'Label 5' => int 0
      'Label 6' => int 0
      'Label 7' => int 1
      'Label 8' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'Label 1' => int 0
      'Label 2' => int 0
      'Label 3' => int 1
      'Label 4' => int 0
      'Label 5' => int 1
      'Label 6' => int 1
      'Label 7' => int 0
      'Label 8' => int 0
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'Label 1' => int 0
      'Label 2' => int 1
      'Label 3' => int 0
      'Label 4' => int 1
      'Label 5' => int 0
      'Label 6' => int 0
      'Label 7' => int 0
      'Label 8' => int 1
```

and I want to create a table that looks like the this.

| Lable | Groups |
| --- | --- |
| Label 1 | C1 |
| Label 2 | C3 |
| Label 3 | C2 |
| Label 4 | C3 |
| Label 5 | C2 |
| Label 6 | C2 |
| Label 7 | C1 |
| Label 8 | C3 |

> Where array 0.1,2 will be used to identify C1, C2, C3. so

```
array 0 = C1
array 1 = C2
array 2 = C3
```

Saya sudah mencoba seperti ini, tetapi hasil yang diharapkan membingungkan dan sejak itu, hanya macet di sini

```
// $dataset->count() = 8
for ($i=0; $i<$dataset->count(); $i++){ 
    
    // $dataset->label($i) = get lable
    echo $dataset->label($i) . "<br>";

    // $results->count() = 3
    for ($j=0; $j<$results->count(); $j++){ 
        if ($dataset->label($i) == array_keys($results->offsetGet($j))[$i]){

            // $results->offsetGet($j) = contains the array above
            echo $results->offsetGet($j)[array_keys($results->offsetGet($j))[$i]];
            echo "<br>";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

already the result of the code that was made like this,
it's really confusing for me to reach the final result like in table.

```html
Label 1
1
0
0

Label 2
0
0
1

Label 3
0
1
0

Label 4
0
0
1

Label 5
0
1
0

Label 6
0
1
0

Label 7
1
0
0

Label 8
0
0
1
```

so think like this to determine whether the label belongs to which group
so the array keys are 0.1,2 to specify C1, C2, C3, e.g.
more precisely the value 1 of each label to determine where the group belongs; and value 0 of each label indicates not a member of the group.

```
0 => 'Label 1' => 1 // then it is a member of C1, and if
0 => 'Label 2' => 0 // is not a member of C1;
1 => 'Label 3' => 1 // then it is a member of C2
2 => 'Label 2' => 1 // and now label 2 is a member of C3
```

```
[
    0 => [
       'Label 1' => 1, // member C1
       'Label 2' => 0,
       'Label 3' => 0,
        . . .
    ],
    1 => [
       'Label 1' => 0,
       'Label 2' => 0,
       'Label 3' => 1, // member C2
        ...
    ],
    2 => [
       'Label 1' => 0,
       'Label 2' => 1, // member C3
       'Label 3' => 0,
       ...
    ]
]
```

Comment: So each label can be assigned to one single group only? Did you try _anything_ that you could show us?

Comment: It's no clear for us with the data you given us, what the output should be. Also you say you're stuck with your loop but there is no loop..

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope you can understand and help me

Comment: Your given array is not consistent with the desired output: `Label 2 => C3` where there is no `Label 2 => 2` in the array. So either adjust your table or your array.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. The key of the Data array is also the key of the Group array. And if label is set to `1` in the Data array, you assign the group name

Comment: Loop over the first sub-array with a `foreach`, the extended syntax gives you access to key and value. If the value is 1, then you want to output `C1` in your second column. Use the key to access the corresponding values in the other two sub-arrays, and output C2 / C3 based on whether those values are 1.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I have updated the question, (again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the first sub-array with a `foreach`, the extended syntax gives you access to key and value. If the value is 1, then you want to output `C1` in your second column. Use the key to access the corresponding values in the other two sub-arrays, and output `C2` / `C3` based on whether those values are 1.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Label</td>
      <td>Group</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($data[0] as $label => $value): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $label; ?></td>
      <td><?php
        if($value == 1) { echo 'C1'; }
        if($data[1][$label] == 1) { echo 'C2'; }
        if($data[2][$label] == 1) { echo 'C3'; }
      ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Live example with reduced data set: https://3v4l.org/qb3FA

Comment: hi friends, what if the number of groups increases, in my case maybe only `C1, C2, C3`.

maybe in the future there will be `C4, C5` 
or even just `C1 and C2` it will display an error.

Comment: You can determine how many sub-arrays you have first, and then perform these checks in another loop in that place.